# Unrecognized migration

Tags: importing-exporting, migrations

I am using this example: https://gist.github.com/2596787 as a base for importing some static HTML to a Drupal 7 fresh install.  Using `drush ms`:

```
Group:                Total  Imported  Unimported  Status  Last imported

HtmlfilesNodeMigration

HtmlfilesNode         2046   0         2046        Idle    2013-01-23 13:58:01
```

I can see that the Migration class seems to be setup.  However when I go to run the migration from drush I get:

```
Unrecognized migration: HtmlfilesNodeMigration                           [error]
```

Trying through the UI, I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'HtmlfilesNodeMigration' not found
```

Any ideas, pointers etc would be a great help.  I can post the info/module/inc files I am using if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a bit of progress.  I had created the HtmlfilesNodeMigration class outside of the actual hook_migrate_api function.

So instead of:

```
return $api;

}

class HtmlfilesNodeMigration extends Migration {
//code
}
```

I needed:

```
return $api;
class HtmlfilesNodeMigration extends Migration {


  }

}
```